# Refactoring Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring

Could anyone give some suggestions on refactoring the following code to 1-2 lines so that it is concise and readable.

```
def func(a, b):
    c = []
    if a:
        c.append(a)
    if b:
        c.append(b)
    return c
```

I tried following:

```
def func(a, b):
    return [a*(a is not None), b*(b is not None)]
```

It won't work if `a` or `b` is a dictionary, etc.

Comment: Why? Brevity doesn't imply clarity.

Comment: you are getting downvoted because you are not showing what efforts you took to do it.

Comment: @RushyPanchal Thanks, I agree. Just curious if I am doing verbosely here and someone has more concise yet readable solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func(a, b):
    return [x for x in [a, b] if x]
```